# Converting Static HTML pages to Wordpress

Tags: css, html

I have copied the HTML page content to the pages of the WordPress.  The words have shown up under Preview but all the CSS and styling are gone.  I have also imported the style.css into the Theme folder.

My question, why my contents missing their corresponding CSS?

Comment: This is going to be difficult to answer without more information. Is the stylesheet loading? Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: Please provide a link to the site, with the little information you have provided my guess is that you aren't linking to your css file properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this code corresponding to the style.css file that is in your main theme folder?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
```

If you want to link to another name other than style.css or you have a different path you would want to use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/pathocss.css">
```

Comment: You should be using `wp_enqueue_style` instead of hard-coding stylesheets into the theme.